# Symfony API platform return IRI even when using Groups annotations

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I there,
I'm trying to use api platform with symfony 4 but I'm unable to load related entities of an object even using normalizationContext and Groups.
For example, I have 2 classes FieldType and Field. Each Field have a single one FieldType. To load the Field with the fieldtype I created the "field" group which I use in Field to load all the propeties and also in FieldType to also load the field type properties. But at the end I still get the IRI in the returned JSON.
Can someone help me to figure out what is wrong?

Here is the code for the 2 classes:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\AUDFieldRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiSubresource;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"field:read"}},
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AUDFieldRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="aud_field")
 */
class AUDField
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups("field:read")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Groups({"field:read"})
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $optional = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=40, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"field:read"})
     */
    private $inputType;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"field:read"})
     */
    private $inputValues;

    /**
     * @var array
     * @ORM\Column(type="json_array", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"field:read"})
     */
    private $specifications;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=AUDFieldType::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"field:read"})
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=AUDAttributeType::class, mappedBy="fields")
     * @Groups({"field:read"})
     */
    private $attributesTypes;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->attributesTypes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getOptional(): bool
    {
        return $this->optional;
    }

    public function isOptional(): bool
    {
        return $this->optional;
    }

    public function setOptional(bool $bool): self
    {
        $this->optional = $bool;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getSpecifications(): ?array
    {
        return $this->specifications;
    }
    public function getSpecification($key): ?array
    {
        return json_decode($this->specifications[$key]);
    }
    public function setSpecifications(?array $specs): self
    {
        $this->specifications = $specs;
        return $this;
    }
    public function setSpecification($key, $value): ?array
    {
        return $this->specifications[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function hasSpecification($key): bool
    {
        return array_key_exists($key, $this->specifications);
    }

    /*public function addSpecification($key, $value): self
    {
        $this->specifications[$key] = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSpecification($key): self
    {
        unset($this->specifications[$key]);
        return $this;
    }*/

    public function getInputValues(): ?string
    {
        return $this->inputValues;
    }

    public function setInputValues(?string $inputValues): self
    {
        $this->inputValues = $inputValues;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getInputType(): ?string
    {
        return $this->inputType;
    }

    public function setInputType(?string $inputType): self
    {
        $this->inputType = $inputType;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getType(): ?AUDFieldType
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function setType(?AUDFieldType $type): self
    {
        $this->type = $type;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|AUDAttributeType[]
     */
    public function getAttributesTypes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->attributesTypes;
    }

    public function addAttributesType(AUDAttributeType $attributesType): self
    {
        if (!$this->attributesTypes->contains($attributesType)) {
            $this->attributesTypes[] = $attributesType;
            $attributesType->addField($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAttributesType(AUDAttributeType $attributesType): self
    {
        if ($this->attributesTypes->removeElement($attributesType)) {
            $attributesType->removeField($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use App\Repository\AUDFieldTypeRepository;

/**
 * @ApiResource(normalizationContext={"groups"={"field:read"}})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AUDFieldTypeRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="aud_field_type")
 */
class AUDFieldType
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"field:read"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Groups({"field:read"})
     */
    private $name;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

End the Postman output for http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/field/1:

```json
{
    "@context": "/api/contexts/AUDField",
    "@id": "/api/field/1",
    "@type": "AUDField",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Identifiant",
    "specifications": {
        "minlength": 4
    },
    "type": "/api/fieldtype/1",
    "attributesTypes": [
        "/api/attributetype/1"
    ]
}
```

And for http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/fieldtype/1:

```json
{
    "@context": "/api/contexts/AUDFieldType",
    "@id": "/api/fieldtype/1",
    "@type": "AUDFieldType"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `normalizationContext` in `AUDFieldType` class or rename it with `field-type:read`.